# sed: How to replace a line with a changeable character?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I'm a beginner for the `sed` command on `Linux`. Now I have one line in the file:

```
exten => *97,ttttt
```

And I'd like to replace this line to two lines:

```
exten => *97,aaaaa
exten => *97,bbbbb
```

If the original text is static, I can write command like this to replace the line:

```
sed -e 's/,ttttt/,aaaaa\nexten => *97,bbbbb/' -i xxxx.txt
```

But somehow the file `xxxx.txt` is generated by script so the `*97` could become `*95` or other thing, so the next time `xxxx.txt` could be like this:

```
exten => *95,ttttt
```

And I have to replace it with these two lines this time:

```
exten => *95,aaaaa
exten => *95,bbbbb
```

In this case I can't execute the `sed` command above cuz it will write `*97` to second line.

Is there a way that I don't need to rewrite `sed` command every time but also can do the job correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to save all data until the number in group 1 and the number in group 2. Then replace it twice with the different string after them and a newline character between them too:

```
sed -e 's/^\(.*\)\(\*[0-9]\+\).*$/\1\2,aaaaa\n\1\2,bbbbb/' infile
```

It yields:

```
exten => *97,aaaaa
exten => *97,bbbbb
```

Comment: @JohnSmith: In the pattern part first content inside escaped parentheses are saved as `group 1`, that can be recovered in the replacement part with `\1` expression. The next parenthesized expression will be saved as `\2`, and so on if there were more of them. You should read a little bit about regular expression or the `sed` manual because this it the most basic knowledge about it.

Answer (score 1):

Its asked for a `sed` solution, but it could also be done with `awk`

```
echo "exten => *97,ttttt" | awk -F, '{print $1 ",aaaaa\n" $1 ",bbbbb"}'
exten => *97,aaaaa
exten => *97,bbbbb
```

It may be some more easy to understand compare to the complex syntax in `sed`
Divide string in two parts by the `,` using `-F,`
Then print first past with `aaaaa` and  a new line `\n` 
So first part again with `bbbbb`